# my jquery code doesnt work in firefox?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have this code in my site to approve posts:

```
function approvePost(idToApprove,moderatorType)
{

var answer = confirm('are you sure to approve post?!');
if(answer)
{

 $.post('submit.php',{idToApprove:idToApprove , moderatorType:moderatorType},result);
 alert('1111');
 function result(data)
 {
     alert(data);
     if(data=="success")
     {
         alert("successful!");
     }
     else alert('fail!');
 }
}
else{
 return false;   
}
}
```

this code fines well in chrome and IE but in firefox the codes after $.post(.....     doesnt work.
i mean alert('1111'); and alert(data); doesnt work!
i dont know why?! what should i do?

thanks

---

if i change the code to this , both of $.post(... work!!!
the problem exists in different computers , it is not because of cache!
i think the problem is from confirm() function. 
if i dont use it , it works fine!!!

```
function approvePost(idToApprove,moderatorType)
{
     $.post('submit.php',{idToApprove:idToApprove , moderatorType:moderatorType},result);

    var answer = confirm('are you sure to approve post?!');
    if(answer){
        $.post('submit.php',{idToApprove:idToApprove , moderatorType:moderatorType},result);
        alert('1111');
        function result(data){ 
            alert(data);
            if(data=="success"){
                alert("successful!");
            }
            else alert('fail!');
        }
    }else{
        return false;   
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried refreshing the page in firefox while holding shift key? it will reload the cached scripts of that page. hold shift and click reload.

Comment: Do you get any console errors? Are you using the Web Developer?

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution!
the problem was because $.post was in if statement. eventhough if condition was true , $.post didnt work!
i dont know why , but i change the code like this and it works properly!

```
function approvePost(idToApprove,moderatorType)
{
var answer = confirm('are you sure to approve post?!');
if(!answer)
{
    return false;
}
    $.post('submit.php',{idToApprove:idToApprove , moderatorType:moderatorType},result);
    alert('1111');
    function result(data)
    { 

        if(data=="success"){
            alert("successful!");
        }
        else alert('fail!');
    }

}
```